# Infinispan communication using rest when values are placed using Hotrod

Tags: rest, infinispan

scenario : in Infinispan 5.3 server , application putting value in cache using Hotrod(address1:port) , but not able to get same value using infinispan rest interface(using same address1:port and same key).
e.g. put "x"="y" in infinispan cache using hotrod . trying to fetch same cached value using  address1:port/rest/cachename/x but not able to get value.

Please provide input as I am new to it, also please provide example if any.

Answer (score 1):

In order to store data via one interface (e.g. HotRod) and retrieve it via a different interface (e.g. REST), you need to enable [compatibility/interoperability mode](http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_interoperability_between_embedded_and_remote_server_endpoints).